# jetpack Compose row/column onClick navigation

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, jetpack-compose-navigation

Please bear with me I don't know how to properly phrase my question, but I'll try my best.

[image]

I made the screen above by putting *muliple composables* together.

I gave the composable carrying the row an onClick function;

```
@Composable
fun MenuGrid(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onMenuCardClick: (Int) -> Unit = {},
) {
    LazyHorizontalGrid(
        rows = GridCells.Fixed(3),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        modifier = modifier
            .height(200.dp)
    ) {
        items(MenuData) { item ->
            MenuCard(
                drawable = item.drawable,
                text = item.text,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(56.dp)
                    .clickable { onMenuCardClick(item.drawable + item.text) }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said earlier I put *multiple composables* together, to form the image above. I arranged the *multiple composables* in a composable, I called `MenuContentScreen`;

```
@Composable
fun MenuContentScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .padding(vertical = 16.dp)) {
        MenuQuote()
        MenuContentSection(title = R.string.favorite_collections) {
            MenuGrid()
        }
    }
}
```

Then I referenced/called the `MenuContentScreen` on the main Composable of that screen `MenuScreen`. (The one defined in NavHost)

```
@Composable
fun MenuScreen() {
    MenuContentScreen(Modifier.padding())

}
```

Which is where the **problem** is, since the onClick function was defined in another composable, I can't use the onClick function for the `MenuScreen`;
[image]

So **MY QUESTION** is there a way I can link the onClick function on `MenuGrid` to `MenuScreen`, maybe creating an parameter on MenuScreen and assigning it to the `MenuGrid`'s onClick function (*which I have tried and got `val cannot be assigned`*), or Any thing at all.

I will greatly appreciate any help. I have been on this like forever. No information is too small please.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to carry onClick lambda till your MenuScreen Composable such as

```
@Composable
fun MenuContentScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onMenuCardClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Column(
        modifier
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .padding(vertical = 16.dp)) {
        MenuQuote()
        MenuContentSection(title = R.string.favorite_collections) {
            MenuGrid(){
               onMenuCardClick()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MenuScreen(
     onMenuCardClick: () -> Unit
) {
    MenuContentScreen(Modifier.padding(), onClick= onMenuCardClick)

}
```

And in you nav graph without passing navController to `MenuScreen`

call

```
MenuContentScreen {
  navController.navigate()
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Thracian. The problem I'm facing now is that navController is not defined in my MenuScreen file. But my NavHost file, which I did accordingly to Android Developers guide. Please how do I solve this without creating a new navController..

Comment: You don't have to pass navController. I updated the answer. You just add callbacks till your navGraph. And inside callback in navgraph use navController

Comment: Thanks for the swift update Thracian. I tried it but I'm getting two errors; Cannot find a parameter with this name: 'onClick',, and No value passed for parameter 'onMenuCardClick'

Comment: I posted it as demonstration with different names but you can name both callbacks to `onMenuCardClick `. Idea here is moving callbacks from inside to outside instead of passing navigationController from outer Composable to inner Composable

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting